# MariaDB Columnstore CONNECT Engine installation

Tags: linux, docker, mariadb, yum, columnstore

I want to install MariaDB Columnstore using Docker: [image](https://hub.docker.com/r/mariadb/columnstore).

However, the base image has no CONNECT Engine installed. Therefore I need to install it myself. Since the image is based on RHEL distribution (Rockylinux), I need to use either yum or dnf.
According to the [docs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/installing-the-connect-storage-engine/), I need to install 2 packages. For that reason I created a Dockerfile:

```
FROM mariadb/columnstore:latest
RUN sudo yum install MariaDB-connect-engine
RUN sudo yum -y install unixODBC #you need to add -y otherwise it will fail
```

Unfortunately the second line returns an error:

```
No match for argument: MariaDB-connect-engine
Error: Unable to find a match: MariaDB-connect-engine
```

I interpret this as there is no such package in yum repository. If I use "dnf", the result is the same.

Is it called differently now and the docs are not up-to-date? Or how could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repo file has been removed.

Download a new one from: https://mariadb.org/download/?t=repo-config&d=Red+Hat+Enterprise+Linux+8&v=11.1

mariadb.repo:

```
[mariadb]
name = MariaDB
baseurl = https://rpm.mariadb.org/11.1/rhel/$releasever/$basearch
module_hotfixes = 1
gpgkey = https://rpm.mariadb.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-MariaDB
gpgcheck = 1
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mariadb/columnstore:latest
COPY mariadb.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/
RUN yum install -y MariaDB-connect-engine unixODBC
```

```
STEP 1/3: FROM mariadb/columnstore:latest
STEP 2/3: COPY mariadb.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/
--> 8625abda63e5
STEP 3/3: RUN yum install -y MariaDB-connect-engine unixODBC
Rocky Linux 8 - AppStream                       689 kB/s |  10 MB     00:15    
Rocky Linux 8 - BaseOS                          1.8 MB/s | 7.2 MB     00:04    
Rocky Linux 8 - Extras                           13 kB/s |  14 kB     00:01    
Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64  5.1 MB/s |  16 MB     00:03    
MariaDB                                         1.4 MB/s | 520 kB     00:00    
Dependencies resolved.
================================================================================
 Package                      Arch     Version                Repository   Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 MariaDB-connect-engine       x86_64   11.1.2-1.el8           mariadb     2.6 M
 unixODBC                     x86_64   2.3.7-1.el8            appstream   453 k
Upgrading:
 MariaDB-columnstore-engine   x86_64   11.1.2_23.02.4-1.el8   mariadb     8.9 M
 MariaDB-server               x86_64   11.1.2-1.el8           mariadb      27 M
Installing dependencies:
 libtool-ltdl                 x86_64   2.4.6-25.el8           baseos       57 k
Installing weak dependencies:
 pv                           x86_64   1.6.6-7.el8            epel         64 k
```

Comment: You are my hero! Everything worked. Many thanks